# How to replace one image in an array with another image in an array using javscript

Tags: javascript

I am scraping HTML, and want to replace images in the articles with images I have hosted on my own infrastructure instead of hotlinking to the other website.

so lets say the article has the following html but with different image names on the page multiple times, and I have no idea of how many images there will be per page, so will have to be an array:

```
<img src="HXXP://domain.com/aaa/aaaa/aaa/123.jpg" alt="asd" style="width:100%">
<img src="HXXP://domain.com/aaa/aaaa/aaa/456.jpg" alt="asd" style="width:100%">
```

and I have extracted those images and uploaded them to my own host and now have a list of images with the following link, which will have the same files names, but different domains and urls

```
HXXP://example.com/bbb/bbbbb/bbbb/123.jpg
HXXP://example.com/bbb/bbbbb/bbbb/456.jpg
```

how to I replace the original links in the html with my own?

I'm thinking I'm going to need some mixture of for loop replace functionality. Does anyone have an example of this at all?

Comment: Is the images in the article have some sort of unique identifier?

Comment: a simple forEach would help you to solve the problem.

Comment: @DenizKaradağ he could do that, but will we know if we are replacing the right image source in the article

Comment: @FrancisG If he has an identifier it would be easier of course. In the worst case file names and paths to be matching. So getAttribute("href") then split the string from last 1-2 "/". then find it in the new url array. Then replace it. As long as file names or path/filenames are unique, it will work perfectly fine

Comment: @DenizKaradağ just like I said he could do that, but then again its not full proof to use the file name as identifier, what if you want to change 123.jpg -> 123_01.jpg?

Comment: this is the thing, i dont know what will come up, at the moment I am getting a list of the img via the ".wp-block-image img" CSS selector, the issue I am thinking about is how do I know I am replacing the image 1 with the correct image one I have uploaded etc. at the moment I cant see any unique identifier other than the URL itself as a whole

Comment: @FrancisG He is the one who uploads the images and creates the url. If he keeps the structure same all the time, it shouldn't be a problem. So with this much given input, this is how he can solve the problem. if there is 2 files with same name, there is nothing we can do for him :)

Answer (score 0):

here is the below code fiddle for your answer, as you said you want to replace the article image with your own, you can fetch the all article images from js by query selector of `getElemetsByTagName` then you can loop through it and replace it from the array, here i assume order of article images are same as the images stored by your own

```js
let myOwnImgs= ['HXXP://example.com/aaa/aaaa/aaa/789.jpg', 'HXXP://example.com/aaa/aaaa/aaa/101.jpg']

var shownImg = document.getElementsByTagName("img");


for(var i =0; i< shownImg.length; i++){
  shownImg[i].src = myOwnImgs[i]  // updating main image with array image
  shownImg[i].alt = myOwnImgs[i].slice(-7)  // for verifying
}
```

```html
<img src="HXXP://domain.com/aaa/aaaa/aaa/123.jpg" alt="123">
<img src="HXXP://domain.com/aaa/aaaa/aaa/456.jpg" alt="456">
```